# "TeX capacity exceeded" because of a couple of raiseboxes in a \section?

Tags: macros, errors, sectioning

In a package, I have the following command defined:

```
\newcommand\fkm{
    \ensuremath{\mathrm{
        \raisebox{-0.1ex}{\rotatebox{22}{f}}\!
        \raisebox{0.2ex}{\rotatebox{-15} {k}}\!
        m\!^{*}
    }}
}
```

It works just as I'd expect in text, but if I say `\section{\fkm}` I get an error saying

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

Why doesn't this work within sections? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to matter if I use the command (`\section{\fkm}`) or the code directly (`\section{$\mathrm{...}$}`) - I still get the error...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The argument of `\section` could be used for the table of contents. In that process, commands within this argument may be expanded and written to the toc file for later use. To prevent expansion, you could use the `\protect` command:

```
\section{\protect\fkm}
```

Or, use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define the command such that it's working in such moving arguments. You might also consider to use the optional argument of `\section` for the toc entry. See: [Fragile and Robust commands](http://texblog.net/help/latex/fragile.html).

Other commands with such moving arguments are `\chapter`, `\subsection` etc. and `\caption`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the error that I get when I try it. However, the solution is to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` works brilliantly - but out of curiosity, what error do you get?