# TeX capacity exceeded, when flexisym scrreport, hyperref, and section heading with math all used together

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, hyperref, koma-script

I'm getting the error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
```

Under the following very specific combination of packages and document class:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\begin{document}
\chapter{When $\ne$.}
\end{document}
```

Removing either the `hyperref`, or `flexisym` package references, or changing the document class to `article` from `scrreport`, or removing the math content from the `\chapter` (or `\section` or `\subsection`) heading, appears to eliminate the issue.

This looks pretty similar to ["TeX capacity exceeded" because of a couple of raiseboxes in a \section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/tex-capacity-exceeded-because-of-a-couple-of-raiseboxes-in-a-section)

but changing the chapter reference to:

```
\chapter{When \protect$\ne$.}
```

doesn't seem to help.  Is this a bug in one of the packages above?  If not, what's the proper way to deal with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of the `toc`

The `\chapter` command has the syntax

```
\chapter[optional argument for the toc]{name of the chapter}
```

If you don't use the `<optional argument for the toc>` then `LaTeX` will try and use `name of the chapter`, which causes issues when you have mathematical content (as in your example) because the `hyperref` package can not make mathematical symbols into hyperlinks.

You can fix it by using (something like)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter[for the toc]{When $\ne$.}
\end{document}
```

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded after most packages (exceptions are discussed in [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before))

As mentioned in the comments, and in [Equations in section heading/title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/equations-in-section-heading-title) you can use `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}`

Comment: There is also the `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` command from `hyperref`, but the OP is still going to need something besides `$\neq$` for the 'PDF' argument....

Comment: @jon: thanks- have included it in my answer

Comment: OK.  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: This also helped me with a related question. I was using `\sectionmark` in my section title (which is weird, but necessary). Thanks so much!