# Turn \mathbb characters bold in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold

I've seen various topics here adressing how to turn math symbols bold, but none of them gives a suitable option for `\mathbb` characters, as in `\mathbb{ABC}`.
I have tested some options to see which commands turn which symbols in bold. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % some math-related packages, not sure which of them are necessary
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm} % for \bm
\usepackage{fixmath} % for \mathbold
\begin{document}
\section{Some text $\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha$ some text} %1
\section{Some text $\boldsymbol{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %2
\section{Some text $\mathbf{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %3
\section{Some text $\pmb{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %4
\section{Some text $\boldmath{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %5
\section{Some text $\bm{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %6
\section{Some text $\mathbold{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %7
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The absence of `\div` in numbers 2 and 6 are not typos, neither is the 'ff' in number 3.) Apparently `\pmb` is the only command which turns `\mathbb{ABC}` bold. But it makes the characters quite ugly, take a close look: (on the right is the normal version)
[image]

If no alternative shows up, I think I'll just use `\pmb` for the `\mathbb` characters and `\boldsymbol` or something for the others.

> Is there any alternative to turn `\mathbb{ABC}` bold?

Comment: "blackboard bold" is the name given to this alphabet because the double strokes are a simulation of bold with chalk on a blackboard, although they have been adopted with specific meanings that no longer have much to do with the "bold" association.  what is the reason/meaning for making them even "more bold"?

Comment: Note that `\boldmath` in math mode is wrong. However, in a math oriented document, formulas should not be made bold according to the context, as the weight of characters carries semantics: a boldface variable is not the same as the normal weight one.

Comment: Traditional typography denoted number sets simply with upright boldface letters. Just see `Bourbaki`'s treatise…

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't know they are meant to be bold. Anyway they don't look as bold as other boldface characters.  
egreg: thanks for the tip, your are right about that. But in my case it is only meant to make all the text/maths in a title look the same, so I think it is not wrong to do it.  
Bernard: It's the first time I hear that. (Somehow I always thought the notation was used since Euler's time, probably it's not.) I've grown up with \mathbb{N}, see.

Comment: I saw this in a list of FAQs to refer new users to, and thought it needed an updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I place three copies in close horizontal proximity by defining `\fakebold{}`.  One can obviously modify it to use more copies, or to apply vertical offset as well.  The horizontal offset is given by `\bshft`, currently set to 0.18pt.

By using the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` feature of `scalerel`, it should work across math styles, so that `$\fakebold{A_b} A_{\fakebold{b}} A_b$` will give the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % some math-related packages, not sure which of them are necessary
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm} % for \bm
\usepackage{fixmath} % for \mathbold
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\bshft
\bshft=.18pt\relax
\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\section{Some text $\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha$ some text} %1
\section{Some text $\boldsymbol{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %2
\section{Some text $\mathbf{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %3
\section{Some text $\pmb{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %4
\section{Some text $\boldmath{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %5
\section{Some text $\bm{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %6
\section{Some text $\mathbold{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text} %7
What comes next is new
\section{Some text $\protect\fakebold{\mathbb{ABC}abc\cosh\div+\alpha}$ some text}%8
\LARGE$\fakebold{\mathbb{ABC}a}\mathbb{ABC}a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

and a close-up:

[image]

Comment: but that's essentially `\pmb` as used in the question, perhaps with slightly different offsets.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I understand that to be the case.  But here, I show the user how to control those offsets.  Perhaps `\pmb` also provides those flexibilities, I do not know.

Comment: OK:-) pmb isn't designed to be flexible (it's really designed not to b eused:-)

Comment: Thanks, I knew there would be some way to do it manually. I'll use `\fakebold` only for the `\mathbb` things and `\bm` for the others, because `\bm` seems to treat `\cosh` exactly as it treats normal text.

Comment: Aargh, I'm getting memory errors: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`. The document I'm working in is a bit lengthy indeed. Perhaps can we solve this by defining a new font or something, so LaTeX does not need to compute things and shift those letters every time again?

Comment: @barto  If you don't need math subscripting of the fake-bolded letters, try this simpler definition which does not rely on `scalerel` solutions: `\def\fakebold#1{\ooalign{$#1$\cr\kern-\bshft$#1$\cr\kern\bshft$#1$}}`

Comment: Still getting the error. (But indeed, I won't be using sub/superscripts inside `\fakebold` because I prefer to set them in `\bm`.) It is an `[input stack size = 5000]` error, so that might indicate what's going wrong. Usually I compile with pdfLaTeX, this time I tried LuaLaTeX too but it gives the same error.

Comment: @barto Here is a definition that avoids the use of `\ooalign` and `scalerel`, if that is the issue: `\def\fakebold#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}#1\kern-\wd0\kern\bshft#1\kern-\wd0\kern\bshft#1}`

Comment: Still getting those errors, but I've been playing around a bit with `\protect\fakebold{\mathbb Z}` followed by another `\protect\fakebold{\mathbb Z}` in one section title: this works when nothing or some characters are in between them, but fails when I put `\bm{abc}` between them. I think I am either overusing `\protect`, or using it in the wrong way. Perhaps it has something to do with `\kern`... (I'm reading through [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736).)

Comment: @barto  That is interesting since `\section{$\protect\fakebold{\mathbb Z}\bm{abc}\protect\fakebold{\mathbb Z}$}` works for a small test problem, using any of the 3 definitions I provided above.  I'm not sure what more I can do at this point.

Comment: I'll try some more things, if necessary I'll build up my document from scratch and see when the error occurs. (If I'm really running out of memory, I would get to know it this way.) If the problem persists, I'll ask another question. Thanks anyway for your assistance.

Comment: Yesss! I found the problem by rebuilding my document: it has something to do with the `hyperref`-package: it compiles when I don't load it but doesn't when I do. I load the package as `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`, but even without `hidelinks` it doesn't work. I tried to load the package in the very beginning of the preambule and at the very end, without success. Probably it is the same problem as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57947): something with the table of contents.

Comment: @barto `hyperref` breaks a lot of things, because it does a lot of redefinition of fundamental items.  Congratulations on finding the issue.

Comment: Apparently the trick is to use `\texorpdfstring{$math$}{some text that doesnt really matter}`. (Perhaps it's a good idea to vote up the comments which are relevant for future readers.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages that do this, but I recommend `unicode-math` if you can use it, or `mathalpha` if PDFLaTeX compatibility is a requirement.

The [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) package is compatible with PDFLaTeX.  It will load the bold version of the double-struck math alphabet you select as `\mathbbb`, if there is one.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}
\( \mathbbb{ABCa}
   \mathbb{ABCa} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Boondox font sample]

In the modern toolchain, `unicode-math` will load a bold Unicode math font automatically if the math font you select has one.  (As of 2019, XITS Math, Libertinus Math and Minion Math do.)  You can select it with `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath`, `\boldmath` or `\mathversion{bold}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\mathbbb[1]{\boldsymbol{\symbb{#1}}}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\( \mathbbb{ABCa}
   \mathbb{ABCa} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: XITS Math sample]

You can also specify a bold math font manually with `version=bold`, for example:

```
\setmathfont[version=bold, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Minion Math Semibold}
```

Finally, `unicode-math` allows you to declare an arbitrary OpenType or TrueType font as a math alphabet with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

Comment: Does Libertinus Math have a bold variant? I don't see it here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertinus-fonts/otf

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I seem to recall this having worked, but it’s been a while. If a math font doesn’t come in bold, you can [make one with `FakeBold`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592046/61644).