# How to get bold version of blackboard bold fonts?

Tags: amsmath

Right now, I have `\mathbb{C}` and `\boldsymbol{\mathbb{C}}` both producing the same character.  What package/command do I need to get a bolder character?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199333/turn-mathbb-characters-bold-in-math-mode (probable duplicate)

Answer (score 4):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, `\boldsymbol\mathbb` works if you load a math font with a bold version (as of July 2019, XITS Math, Libertinus Math or Minion Math) or if you manually load a bold math font with, for example, `\setmathfont[version=bold]{Minion Math Semibold}`.

Otherwise, as Sebastiano beat me to saying, load [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) (formerly `mathalfa`) with a double-struck font that comes in bold (such as `[bb=px]`) and use its `\mathbbb`.

Answer (score 3):

Here there is my proposal as an alternative. You could to use `bb = boondox` + `mathalpha` (as suggest by the user @Davislor - see comment and your nice answer), but it changes the nature of the symbol. You have always the bold.

Here there is a little code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}, \mathbbb{R}, \mathbbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```

and a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Note that the package has been renamed `mathalpha`.

Comment: @Davislor I didn't know and thank you very much. Then in my book I change it, because I use this name.

Comment: It might still be a good idea to use `mathalfa` in our examples for a while, because that’s still supported for backward-compatibility and it might take a while for everyone to update.