# Bold Comma in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, bold

`$\mathbf{0,00042}$ A` renders to

[image]

I think the comma could be a bit more bold. What do I wrong here?

Im using Arial as main font here:

```latex
  5 \setmainfont{Arial}
  6
  7 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  8
  9 \usepackage{amsmath}
 10 \usepackage{unicode-math}
 11 \setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}
 12 \setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
 13 \setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
 14 \setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
 15 \setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}
 16 \setmathfont[range=tt]{Andale Mono}
```

Comment: unlike \symbf, \mathbf selects the a different font rather than different unicode range so it depends which font you have set up for bold roman but it's hard to test as you have not provided a usable test file (and I don't have all the fonts used in your fragment) posting fragments (especially line numbered ) makes it harder for anyone to test answers.

Comment: **Remark:** You seem to be German or at least you use comma as a decimal separator. In that case, consider using `0{,}01` in order to remove the unwanted space after the comma. There are also packages for that, e. g. `icomma`. **Update:** I now see that this is already addressed in Davislor's answer :).

Answer (score 6):

You’re correct: `\mathbf` does not change the weight of symbols other than latters and numbers.  The correct way to get a bold comma (or plus sign, etc.) is to set a bold math version.

As of 2021, there is no sans-serif math font that comes in a bold version, but you can fake one with `fontspec` commands.  Unfortunately, the `range=` and `version=` options of `\setmathfont` do not work together.  For this example, I picked Fira Sans and Fira Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold = 2.5]

\begin{document}
\noindent
$0{,}00042$ A \\
{\bfseries\boldmath
$0{,}00042$ A}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Math/Fira Code sample]

Tweak the value of `FakeBold=` to your taste.  Writing the comma as `{,}` changes the math class to `\mathord`, which removes the spurious space you were getting after it.  By default, TeX thinks that you have two numbers separated by a comma.

An alternative would be to use `siunitx`.