# Can't use command in listing caption

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“TeX capacity exceeded” because of a couple of raiseboxes in a \section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/tex-capacity-exceeded-because-of-a-couple-of-raiseboxes-in-a-section)

I'm not able to use the following command in a listing caption (I think the same applies to headings):

```
\newcommand{\CS}{C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.6ex}{\smaller\smaller\bf \#}}
```

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
   \in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
      ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
     l.10 ]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `\protect\CS` should suffice.

Comment: fragile command in moving argument: use \protect\CS

Comment: got to be a duplicate somewhere, will have a look :)

Comment: Thanks all of you... And who should I accept now?:D

Comment: I voted this question is closed as duplicate (the one I picked is for section rather than caption, but in both cases it's raisebox causing the problem) (writing to table of contents or list of figures respectively)

Comment: I agree. Sorry, but it is very hard to search for a solution, when the error message lacks of expressiveness. (At least for me.)

Comment: For future reference: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736)